# Creating CSV from php

Tags: php, csv

How do I go through a loop in php and basically add it to my array? I'm using this simple code from here - http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php:

```
<?php

$list = array (
    array('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'dddd'),
    array('123', '456', '789'),
    array('"aaa"', '"bbb"')
);

$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');

foreach ($list as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}

fclose($fp);
?>
```

But create the list like this, that should add each line from my db:

```
$data .= str_replace(","," ",$ftitle) . $delimiter .$ccrow['CourseCode']. $delimiter . str_replace(","," ",$ccrow['CourseName']) . $delimiter . $count . $delimiter . "\n";

$list = array(array($data));
```

I get it into my file but it adds it all in the first cell???

Comment: Excel is dumb, it uses `;` instead of `,` as delimiter in CSV.

Comment: @MaximKhan-Magomedov Hm. I'm afraid you are completely wrong. It works just fine with `,` as delimiter

Comment: @MaximKhan-Magomedov while importing into Excel you can choose a custom character (or even sets of characters).

Comment: It's actually locale-specific whether it uses , or ; for preference; but if you import you can override anyway

Comment: As you use multi-dimensional `$list` array, please post the desired output.

Comment: I'm using comma as a delimiter.  It's the default isn't it?

Comment: @Mark Seriously? I never knew! A locale specific delimiter for **comma** separated values... Excel just keeps on giving... O_o

Comment: @deceze - tell me about it :( I suspect it's related to locales that use , as a decimal separator

Comment: @Mark Gee, if only it was possible to represent values which contain the delimiter in CSV... \*headdesk\* ;-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why do you need this:

```
$data .= str_replace(","," ",$ftitle) . $delimiter .$ccrow['CourseCode']. $delimiter . str_replace(","," ",$ccrow['CourseName']) . $delimiter . $count . $delimiter . "\n";
```

You should simply do something like this:

```
while(($ccrow = mysql_fetch_array($result))) {
    fputcsv($fp, $ccrow);
}
```

and it will place everything correctly.

Comment: That works a treat, but I need the other variable $count, how would I add that to each line?

Comment: place `$ccrow["count"] = X;` before fputcsv

Comment: Just out of curiosity, and not something I need to do just yet, but is it possible to change the order of the rows that I add?  This solution adds to the end, what if I needed to add at the beginning for example?

Comment: Nope. You can only append rows to a file. But you can create an array with all rows you want to put into csv ordered correctly, and then put rows from that buffer array into a file.